# Examine and replace characters at end of line or before whitespace

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, whitespace

I currently have two arrays set up, and I am trying to examine the last two letters in a word and replace it with other characters if there is a match with the first array. I currently have it working to do this to the end of the line, but I cannot figure out how to do this for words that are not at the end of a line.

The following is an example of what my arrays might look like. These are populated from a database query. The characters could be any Unicode character, so not necessarily in the range from A-Z or a-z.

```
$array1 = ['mp', 'tm', 'de', 'HK'];
$array2 = ['MAP', 'TM', "DECIMAL", '字'];
```

My current code looks like this:

```
$mystring = "samplemp";
$last = substr($mystring, -2);
$newlast = str_replace($array1, $array2, $last);
if ($last != $newlast){
    $mystring = substr($mystr, 0, 2).$newlast;
}
```

**What I have working:**

So, the code I currently have looks at the last two characters in the string. If the last two characters are "mp" for example it replaces them with "MAP". So if my string looks like:

```
samplemp
```

it gets changed correctly to

```
sampleMAP
```

up to this point everything is working correctly.

**The problem**

The issue I am having is dealing with the words that are not at the end of a string. For example:

```
samplemp okay de     hellotm
blatm theHK end
```

should be replaced with

```
sampleMAP okay DECIMAL     helloTM
blaTM the字 end
```

**I want to be able to account for all white space including spaces, tabs, and carriage returns. However, the whitespace must remain intact and not changed. Spaces must stay as spaces, tabs as tabs, and carriage returns as carriage returns.**

So far, I've been able to figure out that I likely need to use a regular expression using the `\s` escape character to account for whitespace. However, I cannot comprehend how to use this with the str_replace functions which are acting on the arrays. Is there a way to do this? If not, what else should I do to get this to work?

Comment: You are missing a `$` here `$mystring = substr($mystr, 0, 2).newlast;` should be `$mystring = substr($mystr, 0, 2).$newlast;`

Comment: Thank you for your help @ArtisticPhoenix, one thing I did not think about mentioning is that the characters may not necessarily Latin characters, but any Unicode characters. So, the a-z range will not work. I think you may be on to something with the preg_replace function though, I will have to look more into it with trying to search for white space. Also, thank you for pointing out my missing $. I had the $ in my real code, just missed it in my sample here.

Comment: the problem you are having is str_replace, will replace any occurrence of the string. preg_replace, or Regx in general give you a lot more control of where the match happens.

Comment: @kojow7 will you check my answer below and tell is it usefull or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do:

```
$string = <<<EOD
samplemp okay de     hellotm
blatm theHK end
EOD;
$array1 = ['mp', 'tm', 'de', 'HK'];
$array2 = ['MAP', 'TM', "DECIMAL", '字'];

$hash = array_combine($array1, $array2);
foreach($hash as $k => $v) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/'.preg_quote($k).'(?=\s|$)/u', function($m) use($v) {
        return $v;
    },
    $string
    );
}
echo $string,"\n";
```

Where `(?=\s|$)` is a lookahead that makes sure we have any kind of space (ie. space, tabulation, carriage return, linebreak, ...) or the end of the string after the searched key. With this, we keep the white space unchanged.

`/u` is unicode flag.

**Output:**

```
sampleMAP okay DECIMAL     helloTM
blaTM the字 end
```

Comment: Thank you for this and the explanation of what a lookahead is. I had not heard of lookaheads before, and just realized how useful they would be for other situations! I have also modified my original code so it now uses PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR to fetch the data from the database which I hadn't heard of before either. So, that should hopefully make things a bit faster instead of using array_combine.

Comment: How does your method compare with the method mentioned by Josh H?

Comment: @kojow7: My answer is looking after any kind of whitespaces (`\s`) or end of line (`$`) after the word, as you've requested. Josh's answer is looking after a word boundary.

Comment: I actually meant for efficiency, but am awarding you the points nonetheless as it works well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression with a lookahead that matches any sequence of whitespace at the end of the string.

```
$array1 = ['/mp(?=\s*$)/', 'tm(?=\s*$)/', 'de(?=\s*$)/'];
$array2 = ['MAP', 'TM', "DECIMAL"];

$newlast = preg_replace($array1, $array2, $last);
```

Comment: Since the arrays are being populated from the database and may contain more than a hundred items, are you suggesting that I loop through $array1 and concatenate the `/` and `(?=\s*$)/`to each item in the array?

Comment: Yes, that's how to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Without testing you can do something like this

```
$array2 = ['mp' => 'MAP', 'tm' => 'TM', 'de' => "DECIMAL"];

$mystring = "samplemp";
$patt = '/('.implode( '|',array_keys($array2) ) .')\b/';

$newlast = preg_replace_callback($patt , function( $m ) use ($array2){
    return $array2[$m[1]];
}, $mystring);

echo "\n$newlast";
```

Using `preg_replace_callback` you can avoid looping through the array of inputs and instead loop though the matches, which should provide some small increase in performance, seeing that in most cases there will be more possibilities ( inputs ) then actual matches.

The regular expression for this works out to be something like:

```
/(mp|tm|de)\b/
```

So, this will capture `mp` or `tm` or `de` but only with a word break `\b` at the end, as in the end of the string or the end of the word, so it wont match `den` with `de` for example.

The callback part is pretty strait forward, each time a match in the input string is made the callback is triggered, and that match is passed into that function as the first parameter.  The format of the match is just like preg_match works.  Then whatever you return is used as the replacement string.  This just a easy way of access in the key => value pair in the array.

`use` in a closure is just a scope resolution operator, that allows you to pass in variables that would normally be outside the scope of the closure. '

The real advantage to doing it this way, is you don't have to prepare the array using a loop for your pattern, just do implode on it.  Also, it loops on the matches, not on the inputs.  Most of the other answers do a loop to prepare the pattern, then another loop on the pattern.  "Looping on the matches is unavoidable"  and I say Looping loosely just meaning a repetitive operation.

In any case you can test the Regx here

https://regex101.com/r/AYw111/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a hard time fully understanding your code as I am not familiar with callbacks too much. However, without further explanation, I do not see how it is accounting for and preserving whitespace.

Comment: it doesn't account or preserver white space, it ignores it.  The `\b` is a word break or the end of word, so it's matching, the array keys `|` pipe is an or, at the end of a word and replacing it with the array value for that key.

Comment: preg_replace_callback, triggers the callback each time a match is made with the matches `$m`, the `use` part just allows scope for the `$array` variable.

Comment: We are almost there, I think yours will work well, however, I ran a glitch that took quite a while to track down. I do have a period (.) that needs to convert to another character, however, it seems to be throwing off the code because  a period is seen as a regular expression character for any character. What can I do to get around this, and would there be other potential characters that would have the same problem?

Comment: Toto's method actually seems to be working well for me with the `preg_quote` function. I could not figure out how to effectively use this with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using regular expressions.

First convert your patterns to regular expressions and append '\b' to your patterns which means word boundary (space, tab, EOL...):

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
  $array1[$k] = '/'.$v.'\\b/';
}
```

Then replace with preg_replace:

```
$result = preg_replace($array1, $array2, "samplemp okay hellotm");
```

Comment: This will replace it at the end of all words, not just the last word of the string.

Comment: @Barmar I am wanting to replace the last characters of all words in the string.

Comment: @kojow7 That wasn't clear from the code you posted, since you never split `$mystring` into separate words.

Comment: @Barmar I think it should have been clear from the example in my third-last paragraph. I also cannot split $mystring into separate words because then I would lose the exact type of whitespace.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

You can split string into array then check particular word for your replacement. Try this :

```
$array1 = ['mp', 'tm', 'de', 'HK'];
$array2 = ['MAP', 'TM', "DECIMAL", '字'];

$mystring = "samplemp \t okay hellotm";
preg_match_all('/\s+/', $mystring,$space_array);
$space_array = isset($space_array[0])?$space_array[0]:$space_array;
$test_array = preg_split('/\s+/', $mystring);
$change_array= array();
$new_str = "";
foreach ($test_array as $key => $value) {         
    $last = substr($value, -2);
    $newlast = str_replace($array1, $array2, $last);
    if ($last != $newlast){
        $value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value)-2).$newlast;
    }
    $value .= isset($space_array[$key])?$space_array[$key]:"";
    $change_array[] = $value;    
}
var_dump(implode("", $change_array));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, as part of my request it must be able to account for all types of white space, not just spaces.

Comment: @kojow7 I have edited my code for  all types of spaces. Now check it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick function I knocked together that should do what you need. It splits the string, then looks for the last 2 letters in array1. If it finds it, it replaces the end letters with the ones from array2. If it reaches the end of the loop and hasn't returned, then it returns the original string.

```
<?php

function replaceString($string)
{
    $array1 = ['mp', 'tm', 'de'];
    $array2 = ['MAP', 'TM', "DECIMAL"];
    $first = substr($string, 0, -2);
    $last = substr($string, -2);
    $split = [
      'start' => $first,
      'end' => $last,  
    ];
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
        if ($val == $split['end']) {
            $word = $split['start'].$array2[$key];
            return $word;
        }
    }
    return $string;
}


echo replaceString("samplemp")."\n";
echo replaceString("okay")."\n";
echo replaceString("hellotm")."\n";
```

sampleMAP 
okay 
helloTM

Live Example HERE https://3v4l.org/fJCIY

Comment: You seem to be manually splitting the string here. I need something that keeps the original whitespace intact.

Answer (score 1):

To go a little simpler than some of the other answers already here:

```
$mystring = <<<EOD
samplemp okay MADE  de     hellotm
blatm theHK end
EOD;
$array1 = ['mp', 'tm', 'de', 'HK'];
$array2 = ['MAP', 'TM', "DECIMAL", '字'];
foreach($array1 as $key=>$v){
    $mystring = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($v)."\b/u", $array2[$key], $mystring);
}
```